# Altering the font size without changing characters in the sentence

Tags: ms-word

I have a doc file .I am attaching the doc file here.`https://github.com/smidhunraj/doc`.Now the font size is 6.5. I have to change the font size to 10.My condition is that the sentences should contain the exact words before and after the font size change.Is it possible.If so how can i do that

For example  the first line  when doc file is having font size 6.5 is

```
his mind that parnellite criticism, then very loud in the house, could be lulled by a good
```

When I change the font size to 10 it changes to

```
his mind that parnellite criticism, then very loud in the house,
```

Only this much word in the first line

How to keep it as in `his mind that parnellite criticism, then very loud in the house, could be lulled by a good` in the first line

Even after font size change,This is to be followed for all lines.

Comment: Quite obviously, if you're going to increase the font size, but want to retain the same characters per line, you need to reduce the character spacing. In any event, this is not a programming question and, as such, if off-topic here.

Comment: For an idea of what would be involved in changing the character spacing programmatically so that pre-determined ranges all fit on one line, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/40613-how-resize-paragraph-range-include-single-line.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look at is font kerning, see [Font kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)

But also, bigger fonts take up more space so inevitability you're going to hit a limit that you can't get it on a single line anymore. Reducing the page boundaries may be an option then.